# Xamarin UI Test App project template missing

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, uitest

After upgrading VS 2017 to 15.7, the project template for UI Test App (Xamarin.UITest | Cross Platform) is now missing.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open VS 2017.
2. File -> New -> Project
3. Choose "Test" in the explorer pane.

Expected Results:

All versions of the the UI Test App templates for Xamarin should be shown.
Actual Results:

Only Unit Test Project & Coded UI Test (.Net Framework) are shown.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in VS2017 version 15.7.3.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/249286/xamarin-ui-test-app-project-template-missing.html

Thanks
Santosh